# CKEditor case-sensitive attribute names

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

How can I use CKEditor with case-sensitive attribute names?

I want to edit HTML templates for angular 2 and attributes like `ngModel` CKEditor transfers to `ngmodel`, and as a result, the template crashed.

I already set `config.allowedContent` to `true`.
Please help, how can I configure ckeditor?

Comment: Setting `allowedContent` to `true` is not a magical solution for everything that does not work as expected in CKEditor. We need more details and your code - what does your HTML template look like, how do you insert in into CKEditor, what is your configuration, what happens if you try to do the same on a plain `<textarea>` or a `contenteditable` element.

Comment: template looks like this <input bindon-ngModel /> and I use <textarea> as container, but not understand what is this for. I found i ckeditor code simple replace all attributes toLowerCase(), no options, no configs. BUT. W3 sais - The HTML5 standard does not require lower case attribute names.

Comment: I have a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FMADTkPkUvx9CwMy6yzz) to demonstrate this issue. Also we it looks like multiple people have had this issue unsolved: http://quedig.com/questions/35630160/ckeditor-case-sensitive-attribute-names/ http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-stop-CKEditor-forcing-all-source-lowercase-tags